# Zend checkbox array with key value issue

Tags: php, zend-framework, checkbox, zend-form, zend-form-element

I have a question about the zend_form_element_checkbox from zend.

I have a form with multiple checkboxes. And when I send this form, I logically receive an array of params that look like that :

```
array("controller" => my_controller, ...., "checkbox_name" => array ("0" => firstCheckedValue, "1" => secondCheckedValue, ...) )
```

I create each element this way :

```
$checkbox = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('checkbox_name');
$checkbox->setCheckedValue($valueVar)->setIsArray(true);
$this->addElement($checkbox);
```

And I display each one like that :

```
$this->form->checkbox_name->renderViewHelper();
```

But I would like to have the received params format this way :

```
array("controller" => my_controller, ...., "checkbox_name" => array ("firstCheckedValue" => false, "secondCheckedValue" => true, ...) )
```

In other words, I want the HTML checkboxes look like that :

```
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="checkbox_name[firstCheckedValue]">
<input type="checkbox" value="false" name="checkbox_name[secondCheckedValue]">
...
```

*(the boolean value is not for the checked state of the checkbox).*

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$checkbox = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('first');
$checkbox->setCheckedValue($valueVar)->setIsArray(true)->setBelongsTo('checkbox_name');
$this->addElement($checkbox);
$checkbox = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('second');
$checkbox->setCheckedValue($valueVar)->setIsArray(true)->setBelongsTo('checkbox_name');
$this->addElement($checkbox);
```

Docs: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.advanced.html

> Zend_Form::setElementsBelongTo($array): Using this method, you can
>   specify the name of an array to which all elements of the form belong.
>   You can determine the name using the getElementsBelongTo() accessor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$checkbox = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('checkbox_name');
$checkbox->attribs(array('name' => 'impression[' . $valueVar . ']');
$checkbox->setCheckedValue($valueVar)->setIsArray(true);
$this->addElement($checkbox);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response :)
I've made a mistake when discribing the wanted html. I will edit.
However this method doesn't works because the '[',']' are escaped when I do :
    `$this->form->getElements()`
I see the checkboxes are named :
`checkbox_namefirstCheckedValue` instead of `checbox_name[firstCheckedValue]`
And of course this create an issue because when I do :
`$this->form->checkbox_name->renderViewHelper();
`
checkbox_name doesn't exist anymore ...